# How to show future images actual size when click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I run the code only the first image is showing on click and when I click others, the first image will be the one to show.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

function my(course) {
  var img = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv img')[0];
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = '<?php echo $image[0] ?>';
  captionText.innerHTML = "future Ad full image";
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item <?php if($i == 0 ) echo 'active'; ?>" id="myDiv"><img onClick="my(this);" class="myImg" id="my" style="height:400px; object-fit: cover;" src="<?php echo $image[0] ?>"></div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

When i run the code only the first image is showing on click and when i clik others the first image will be the one to show. have try my best please i need help

[image]

Comment: I made you a proper snippet. Please remove the PHP and add more than one image. For example from placeholder.com

Comment: try to use style to img when click :`height:auto;width:auto;`

Comment: Thank @mplungjan but i want the image be dynamic fetching from database

Comment: But that is not relevant to the code WE need to test your issue is it?

Comment: there is array of images which i want to push to javascript to display the images.  <div class="item <?php if($i == 0 ) echo 'active'; ?>" id="myDiv"><img onClick="my(this);" class="myImg" id="my" style="height:400px; object-fit: cover;" src="<?php echo $image[0] ?>"></div> the code is a part of a slider so each image in the slider should be able to display when click but only one image is display for all image click